# sed with capturing group

Tags: regex, sed

I have strings like below

```
VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data;
IPC_FD_1_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data
BRAKE_FD_2_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data
```

I want to insert `_Moto` in between as below

```
VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_data
IPC_FD_1_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_data
BRAKE_FD_2_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_data
```

But when I used `sed` with capturing group as below

```
echo VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data | sed 's/_In_*\(_data\)/_Moto_\1/'
```

**I get output as:**

```
VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_Moto__data
```

Can you please point me to right direction?

Comment: Can something like this `echo VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data | sed 's/_In_data/_In_Moto_data/'` will work for your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though you could use simple substitution of `IN` string(considering that it is present only 1 time in your Input_file) but since your have asked specifically for capturing style in `sed`, you could try following then.

```
sed 's/\(.*_In\)\(.*\)/\1_Moto\2/g'  Input_file
```

Also above will add string `_Moto` to avoid adding 2 times `_` after `Moto` confusion, Thanks to @Bodo for mentioning same in comments.

Issue with OP's attempt: Since you are NOT keeping `_In_*` in memory of `sed` so it is taking `\(_data_\)` only as first thing in memory, that is the reason it is not working, I have fixed it in above, we need to keep everything till `_IN` in memory too and then it will fly.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning an additional small issue. The modified script adds `_Moto` without a trailing `_`  to avoid the two `_` in the example output `VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_Moto__data`

Comment: @Bodo, thank you for letting know, added in my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/_[^_]*$/_Moto&/' file
VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_data
IPC_FD_1_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_data
BRAKE_FD_2_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_Moto_data
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can directly replace the matching string with below command

`echo VIN_oFDCAN8_8d836e25_In_data | sed 's/_In_data/_In_Moto_data/'`