# How do I output only a capture group with sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have an input file

```
Werkzeug==2.0.2 # https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug
ipdb==0.13.9  # https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb
psycopg2==2.9.1  # https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2
watchgod==0.7  # https://github.com/samuelcolvin/watchgod

# Testing
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mypy==0.910  # https://github.com/python/mypy
django-stubs==1.8.0  # https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs
pytest==6.2.5  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest
pytest-sugar==0.9.4  # https://github.com/Frozenball/pytest-sugar
djangorestframework-stubs==1.4.0  # https://github.com/typeddjango/djangorestframework-stubs

# Documentation
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sphinx==4.2.0  # https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
sphinx-autobuild==2021.3.14 # https://github.com/GaretJax/sphinx-autobuild

# Code quality
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
flake8==3.9.2  # https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
flake8-isort==4.0.0  # https://github.com/gforcada/flake8-isort
coverage==6.0.2  # https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy
black==21.9b0  # https://github.com/psf/black
pylint-django==2.4.4  # https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django
pylint-celery==0.3  # https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-celery
pre-commit==2.15.0  # https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit

# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
factory-boy==3.2.0  # https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy

django-debug-toolbar==3.2.2  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar
django-extensions==3.1.3  # https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
django-coverage-plugin==2.0.1  # https://github.com/nedbat/django_coverage_plugin
pytest-django==4.4.0  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django
```

and I am trying to extract the parts before the `#` for every line beginning with `pytest` using this command

`sed -nE "s/(^pytest.+)#/\1/p" ./requirements/local.txt`

Expected output

```
pytest==6.2.5  
pytest-sugar==0.9.4  
pytest-django==4.4.0
```

Actual output

```
pytest==6.2.5   https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest
pytest-sugar==0.9.4   https://github.com/Frozenball/pytest-sugar
pytest-django==4.4.0   https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django
```

Any help to get the expected?

These refs have not helped solve this particular problem

- [How can I output only captured groups with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/how-can-i-output-only-captured-groups-with-sed)
- [sed with capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949687/sed-with-capturing-group)

Comment: You're only matching up to the #. Nothing after it is part of the matched text and thus not changed and thus printed out... easy fix is to include everything after the # in your RE too.

Comment: Right! changing to `sed -nE "s/(^pytest.+)#.*/\1/p" ./requirements/local.txt` solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: [How to extract text from a string using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568859/) and [How to use sed to extract substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675179/) and probably more are quite helpful.

Comment: Changing to `sed -nE "s/(^pytest.+)#.*/\1/p"` may have solved your problem for this particular input file, but that `sed` command will still have issues: when 1) there is no `#` character, 2) there are more than one `#` characters, in the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the regex after `#`. This should solve it:

```
$ sed -nE "s/(^pytest.+)#.*/\1/p" ./requirements/local.txt
```

Comment: Even though OP's examples doesn't show but a property file may or may not have comment section starting with `#` in each line. This command assumes `#` will always be there. So just having a line with `pytest==124` won't be matched

Comment: N.B. This will also capture the white space before the `#`, perhaps `sed -nE 's/(^pytest\S+)\s*#.*/\1/p' file`?

Comment: In addition to @anubhava's comment, your regex will capture a part of comment if there are more than one `#` characters in the line.

Comment: For a more generic approach, please check the other answers. Mine simply pointed out what he missed in his very particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^(pytest[^=]*=[^[:blank:]]*).*/\1/p' file

pytest==6.2.5
pytest-sugar==0.9.4
pytest-django==4.4.0
```

However a `grep -o` solution would be even simpler:

```sh
grep -o '^pytest[^=]*=[^[:blank:]]*' file

pytest==6.2.5
pytest-sugar==0.9.4
pytest-django==4.4.0
```

**Explanation:**

- `^pytest`: Match `pytest` at the start
- `[^=]*`: Match 0 or more of any character except `=`
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `[^[:blank:]]*`: Match 0 or more of non-whitespace characters

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` one-liner would be:

```
sed -e '/^pytest/!d' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*#.*//' file
```

The first expression deletes lines which don't begin with `pytest`. The second one deletes the comment portion (including blanks before the `#`), if any.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` you could try following. Using `match` function of `awk` here, written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any any. Simple explanation would be, using `match` function of `awk` to match regex `^pytest[^ ]*` to match starting value of pytest till 1st occurrence of space and print the matched value by using `substr` function of `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/^pytest[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk` try following where making use of `RS` variable of it.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)pytest[^ ]*' 'RT{sub(/^\n*/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative using `awk`, you might also set the field separator to `#` preceded by optional spaces, and print the first column if it starts with pytest

```
awk -F"[[:blank:]]*#" '/^pytest/ {print $1}' ./requirements/local.txt
```

Output

```
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-sugar==0.9.4
pytest-django==4.4.0
```

---

If the `#` is not always present, you could also make the match more specific to match the number, and then print the first field:

```
awk '/^pytest[^[:blank:]]*==[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*/ {print $1}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/^pytest/s/#.*//p' input_file
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-sugar==0.9.4
pytest-django==4.4.0
```